# error: '(Class object)' does not name a type

Tags: c++

I have a header file containing this class definition:

```
class visitorlist {
        struct Node {
            visitor vis;
            Node* next;
        };
        Node* head;
        Node* tail;
    public:
        visitorlist() {     //written here to have it as inline.
            head = NULL;
            tail= NULL;
        }
        ~visitorlist();
        int lengthvl();
        void add(const visitor);
        void popandexit();
        void transfer(visitorlist);
        void deletenode(Node*);
        int refiprio();
        int refioffno();
        int refifloor();
        visitor reravi();
        bool isempty();
        Node* rehead();

    };
```

and in a source file with the above header included I have:

```
Node* visitorlist::rehead() {
    return head;
}
```

This causes an `error: 'Node' does not name a type`.
Isn't Node on the scope of the function?

Comment: `Node` is nested inside of `visitorList`, so you would need `visitorList::Node`, but it is a private class so the name is not visible to the outside.

Comment: but will that be sufficient?

Comment: Okay, thanks guys. Such fast answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
visitorlist::Node* visitorlist::rehead() {
    return head;
}
```

Or, since C++11:

```
auto visitorlist::rehead() -> Node* {
    return head;
}
```